# Exact match for a spanish word

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working with Javascript and would like to have a regex to find an exact match of a word, I usually could do this:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, "gm");
```

Where `word` comes from an array, however with this expression `\bsé\b`, with this block

```
no lo sé muy bien
casé
sénégal
```

Is not working as expected, does regex has any special issue with letters with accent marks? What is the approach I should take?

Thanks!

---

POST-EDIT: Given regex won't support accents by default, I ended up doing this

```
function enhanceRegex(word) {
  const accents = ["á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú"];
  return accents.includes(word.toLowerCase().slice(-1))
    ? `\\b${word}(\\s|!|\\?|\\.|,|;|:)+(\\b)?`
    : `\\b${word}\\b`;
}
```

basically, I'm adding the most common scenarios I'll have for my texts, probably is not the best but it helps.

Comment: The following is the equivalent of `indexOf` if it comes to [internationalization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) and locale-based [word-segmentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter#examples). The index of `'sé'` within `'no lo sé muy bien\ncasé\nsénégal'` is `6` ...prove... `Array.from(new Intl.Segmenter('es', { granularity: 'word' }).segment('no lo sé muy bien\ncasé\nsénégal')).find(({ segment }) => segment === 'sé')?.index ?? -1` ...for this alone I vote for a reopening.